# How does Stack Overflow determine the 'interestingness' of a question?

Tags: support, front-page, interesting-page

From what I can tell, it seems like the 'interestingness' of a question depends on a few things:

- Time (less time elapsed since asking = more 'interestingness')
- Has an accepted answer (accepted answer = less 'interestingness')
- Views (more views = more 'interestingness')

I know I'm probably missing a few parameters. I'm just wondering how the 'interestingness' of a question is calculated.

Comment: I believe it is based *primarily* on either your favorite tags, or the tags in which you mostly participate. (Unless you are talking about ["hotness"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=hotness), which is something different entirely.)

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not referring to the [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot). I'm talking about the [interesting tab](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting).

Comment: @CodyGray: indeed -- you can see which tags apply by going to http://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current

Comment: Thanks, @Qantas. Forgot about that feature, it is slightly creepy how well it nails my interests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is documented [in the blog post that announced it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/):

> Here’s how it works. Starting with a list of the last 3,000 active questions:
>
> - drop questions containing any of your ignored tags
> - drop closed questions if you lack the reputation required to vote for reopening
> - drop questions scoring -4 or lower
> - Next, apply the following score formula to the remaining questions:
>
> ...

...I'll let you [click through to read the full details](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/), but as a spoiler: views do not do what you think they do, at all.

Comment: Would be useful to also drop closed question where one *already* voted to reopen (aka may not do so again). Unless that's too expensive a query... which, thinking about it, may well be the case.