# Closed question shown on the front page as interesting

Tags: bug, closed-questions, interesting-page

A [question closed as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009217/area-enclosed-by-contour-lines) is still shown in the list of top questions, even though it has been closed as a duplicate for 45 minutes (the screenshot is a bit old).

> [image]

Is this by design or a bug? Shouldn't closed questions disappear from this list? Isn't that part of the reason for closing them?

Note 1: I started editing the question while it was open, but didn't save it until after it was closed. Can that be the reason why it's still shown?

Note 2: The question was closed (correctly) by a gold badge holder, thus it was not reviewed by 5 people. Is it possible it's kept on the front page since only one user has evaluated it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to my question, and this is apparently *by design*.

In [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257921/how-does-stack-overflow-determine-the-interestingness-of-a-question), asking for how the "interestingness" is determined, [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) answers with a link to the following [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) from 2010.

I'll do as Shog and refer interested people to the blog post for more details, but the part answering my question is:

> Starting with a list of the last 3,000 active questions
>
> - drop closed questions *if you lack the reputation required to vote for
>   reopening*