# Only have my tags ON and OFF in the different feeds

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, answers, filtering

I'm one of the newcomers here, and it's actually my first post on Meta.

I don't fully grasp why my main feed of StackOverflow has some random questions (or at least what appears to be random) with random tags that aren't from my favorite tags pool.

I can understand that we'd want to widen our horizons and not blind ourselves in our small little universe, and also that it's just the most recent question that the engine could find (and it so happens to not be in my favorite tags).

But what I would like to be able to do (maybe a setting I don't know about) is simply filter *everything* but the fews tags I have, because I simply cannot even understand 90% of the questions that show up on my feed, and on the ones I can barely grasp there is simply no way I can answer them in some decent manner.

And I'd rather have older/outdated (12 minutes lifetime on the page 1 feed, right?) questions that I can answer than a lot of questions that just cluster my feed.

I feel like this is a more efficient way to

- Have more answers on all the questions.
- A better ability for me to learn (because I would only get the language(s) I actually understand)
- More reputation for everyone and a stronger feeling of evolution. Which is kind of a fake reason because everyone's reputation would increase the same way if we actually had the chance to see those questions.

I know I could go to "Unanswered - my tags", but then this would filter out all the potentially cool questions I would like to read that already have an answer (which could also be a wrong answer for what it's worth), and that negates the ability to learn from other questions.

Anyway, am I getting something wrong here ? Or did I just have the greatest idea of mankind?

Comment: What do you consider to be your *"main feed"*? The home page? Questions page? Which tab? There are various views on the questions available, or you can just search for all questions in your favourite tags (http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq).

Comment: I simply meant the home page yes, the simple .com, "interesting" questions. Which is the tab i spend 99% of my time in

Comment: For information on that tab, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257921/3001761.

Comment: Try the [hidden beta "recommended questions"](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended) tab.