# Is there any way to get a better question feed?

Tags: support, search

I've started answering questions on this website very recently, and have been having trouble finding questions that are within my ability to answer. There's 2 options that I've found so far to filter it down, but they've been generally unsatisfactory.

1. Tags
   With tags, I can filter on a single tag, and I'm immediately taken to all questions with that tag exactly. While this is handy if I'm in the mood to delve into Python for example, there's no way to see other questions that I would be able to possibly answer.
2. Questions
   With this option, I'm thrust into a huge pit of everything. There's all sorts of questions (most of which I don't have the faintest clue about what they're about), and considering the rate at which new ones come out, this is very impractical if I want to answer some questions.

For example, another question based site has a tailored feed for each of its users to get to see responses in categories that they care about. Even being able to see questions of multiple tags or a customized question feed would be immensely helpful, but is there anything in the works to make it easier to find questions that a particular user would find interesting/relevant? Is there anything in the works of such a feature? Any particular reasoning why this is not done?

Comment: focus on helping cleaning up the crap questions by down voting them into oblivion, `-5` or less score and they disappear from **everyones** feed! Spread the word!

Comment: Wait I just saw a -5 scored question?

Comment: It is implied **front page feed**.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Set up your [favorite tags](//stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#interesting-tags), then search for `intags:mine` to get started with only questions from your favorite tags. If you like, you can shove in a few more search terms; I use [`intags:mine isanswered:no hasaccepted:no closed:0 score:1`](//stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20isanswered%3ano%20hasaccepted%3ano%20closed%3a0%20score%3a1) to find questions that haven't been answered well, but are worth answering. (`isanswered` only checks whether there's a *positively-scored* answer. `score:1` includes anything with a higher score than 1, too.)

Comment: Is there a way to have your default search to be intags:mine, or would that need to be typed in each time?

Comment: @Untitled123: You'd have to type that in each time, or bookmark the resulting URL.

Comment: @Untitled123 Or create a [Bookmarklet](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154) that executes some JavaScript that fills in the search text box for you.

Comment: It'd be slick if *that* could be saved under one of these new-fangled tabs that rolled out recently...

Comment: @Nathan Is there any place where I could find a list of search term choices?

Comment: @Untitled123 After you make a search, on the right side there's an "Advanced Search tips" link containing all search terms.

Comment: @PeterTirrell Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags)?

Comment: Awesome answer - with neat formatting for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [Interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) Questions tab?

I usually browse these and do find some interesting questions, but YMMV.

Per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86858/216322) the tab displays:

> questions that are tagged with your favorite tags or tags you're active in more than other questions.

For more details see [How does Stack Overflow determine the 'interestingness' of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257921/how-does-stack-overflow-determine-the-interestingness-of-a-question)

Comment: Maybe it's because I have not answered enough questions, but the interesting questions tab is a complete mess for me right now. It'd be nice if we could save a query under a tab though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go back in time to when Stack Overflow was not completely saturated.

Otherwise, no.

Comment: To be fair, even back in the day the homepage was generally still mostly crap.  Being 95% crap instead of 99% crap is still a lot of crap.

Comment: @Servy: :D​​​​​ Well at least the 5% wasn't already answered.

Comment: As much as everyone wants to hate on this answer, it is a fact, all the reasonable questions that are *easy* have been asked ad nauseum in the mainstream language tags and I am sure 99% of everything now is a duplicate or off-topic in some other way, that is kind of how it works and was inevitable. This is what directly drove the word **quality** out of the charter statement and got what we have today. **quantity** is king now, the idea seems to be the more duplicates the easier it will be to find the answer mentality. Reputation scores have been diluted to the point of pretty much nothing.

Comment: and the more ads you can place on the all the duplicates, thus more impressions as people search for a **quality** answer amongst all the duplicates.